# Http 415 Unsupported Media type error with JSON POST

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, http-error

I am trying to execute project
https://github.com/bava/springrest-book/tree/master/Chapter4/final/quick-poll-ch4-final

My controller is 
https://github.com/bava/springrest-book/blob/master/Chapter4/final/quick-poll-ch4-final/src/main/java/com/apress/controller/PollController.java

Only change i have done is using Lombok ( not in Poll class for now )

```
@ToString   
@Entity
public class Option {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="OPTION_ID")
    @Getter 
    @Setter
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="OPTION_VALUE")
    @Getter 
    @Setter
    private String value;
}
```

I am getting error

```
{"timestamp":1448542212469,"status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type","exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException","message":"Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported","path":"/polls"}
```

When sending a POST request

```
{
    "question": "Who will win SuperBowl this year?",
    "options": [
                       {"value": "New England Patriots"},
                       {"value": "Seattle Seahawks"},
                       {"value": "Green Bay Packers"},
                       {"value": "Denver Broncos"}]
}
```

Not sure what i am doing wrong
[image]
**Note** : Get is working fine ( can try it only with 0 entries for now )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must specify the `Content-type` for the request you are making as seen below.

[image]